# how to display a datable from webservice using SOAP in a spinner oF Android

Tags: android, database, soap

I am still new in this.
I connected my android app to *SQL Server* using a web-service written in `Asp.net` (visual studio).
I used SOAP, I want to access the datable written in the web-service and put it in a spinner.

This is my code in Visual Studio *(web service)*

//get product from inventory

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataTable getProduct()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebConnectionString"].ToString();
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SmallDescription from [Product]", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("getproduct");
        dt.Load(reader);
        conn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

And this is my `java` code:

```
    Thread nt = new Thread() {


                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // method getproduct

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                            METHOD_NAME);
                    final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    // result.getPropertyInfo(result, pi);

                    /**************** HTTP Post ******************/
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                            URL);

                    try {

                        androidHttpTransport.call(
                                warehouselist_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Not working", e.toString());
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        // "Not working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hola",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            TextView e = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                            SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                            SoapObject nameResult = (SoapObject) resultRequestSOAP
                                    .getProperty(0);

                            int count = nameResult.getPropertyCount();
                            //e.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new
                            StringBuilder();
                            /*
                             * Retrieve one property from the complex
                             * SoapObject response
                             */

                            for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
                            SoapObject simpleSuggestion = (SoapObject)
                         nameResult.getProperty(i);
                            stringBuilder.append(simpleSuggestion.getProperty(
                     "Small Description").toString());
                            stringBuilder.append("\n");
                             }
                             String temp = stringBuilder.toString();
                            // MY QUEST IS HERE HOW TO DISPLAY IT IN A SPINNER!!!!!!
                        }
                    });

                }
            };

            nt.start();

        }
    });
  }
}
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to parse your database response and stored into array list or in array whatever you like,if response is in **Json** format then you can use **JsonArray** or **JsonObject** to parse your response or if response in **xml** then you can use **DOM** or **SAX** parser as u like, after you have to create one spinner adapter e.g. [here](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107), pass your array list or array to the adapter and set as whatever your requirement ,and for more help [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/12/android-populating-spinner-data-from-mysql-database/) is the best example for loading database response into a spinner.